# My Else if statement is not working properly what is the issue?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

i am new in C# and understanding how the if statement works i wrote these code but there seems to be a problem with it.When i write something that is 50 or greater  and less then 60 it says Passed but the else if statement is not working.Whenever i write something greater then 60 nothing happens my program closes.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please state your marks........");
        string uservalue = Console.ReadLine();
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(uservalue);

        if (x >=50)
        {
            if ( x <= 59)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("You Passed");
            }
        }
        else if (x >=60)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Passed Grade B");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: If something is greater than 60, it is also greater than 50. Thus, the first `if`s condition is true and the `else` part is never reached.

Comment: else cannot be reached beause something that is greater than 60 is always greater than 50, too

Comment: `if (x >= 50 && x < 60)` . Since every value over 60 is also over 50, it never looks into the `else` branch.

Comment: Step through it with the debugger and you'll see how the code executes and behaves

Comment: Please avoid *"I am new in ..."*, because it doesn't help anyone to answer your question, and is pure noise. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) on Meta StackExchange.

Comment: @user202729 Telling us he is new could prevent us from being to complex in our answers though?

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for the Tip but i didnt want people laughing at my silly code im pretty new in C# ive done front end stuff most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

```
    ...
    if (x >= 50 && x < 60) {
        Console.WriteLine("You Passed");
    }
    else if (x >= 60) {
        Console.WriteLine("Passed Grade B");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`if (x >= 50)` is a weaker condition than `if (x >= 60)`. This means that if the former is `true`, then program control never considers the `(x >= 60)` case.

The solution here is to deal with the `(x >= 60)` case first.

Answer (score 1):

You should swap the condition and the code should be as follows and would not require the additional condition check for <=59:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please state your marks........");
    string uservalue = Console.ReadLine();
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(uservalue);

    if (x >=60)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Passed Grade B");
    }
    else if (x >=50)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("You Passed");            
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with this (unless it breaks a C# coding style)? See my other comment. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I don't understand it. Let's wait to hear from the C# experts. I'll upvote this if they go silent: it's broadly what I would do in C.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest you to use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, because the user may enter non-integer value. And fix the if condition like that;

```
string uservalue = Console.ReadLine();
int x;
if(!int.TryParse(uservalue,out x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input ! ");
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
if (x >= 50 && x < 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You Passed");
}
else if (x >= 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Passed Grade B");
}
```

Comment: It's funny (to me anyway) that the C# guys don't think about reordering the `if` block. Is this a style thing?

Comment: I'm not a C# guy :D and maybe the OP has a reason for this order... I tend to keep the cases with the least code as last, like let's say output an error or something.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your first if statement && x < 60.
It should look line `if (x >=50 && x < 60)`